# Handling job/step exceptions with asynchronous TaskManager

Tags: java, asynchronous, exception, spring-batch

I can't find a proper way to handle spring-batch exception in asynchronous context.

When I set a `ThreadPoolTaskManager` to my `JobLauncher`, the real job/step exception is not logged anymore. Instead the log will be something like:

```
org.springframework.batch.core.JobInterruptedException: Job interrupted by step execution
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:165)
at ...
```

I tried to resolve this adding a `JobExecutionListener` like this:

```
@Override
public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    List<Throwable> jobExceptions = jobExecution.getFailureExceptions();
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(jobExceptions)) {
        Throwable lastJobException = jobExceptions.get(jobExceptions.size() - 1);
        LOGGER.error("Spring-Batch error at job level", lastJobException);
        String lastJobExceptionMessage = ExceptionUtils.getRootCauseMessage(lastJobException);

        // storing message in ExecutionContext for the batch-admin webapp
        String message = "";
        if (jobExecution.getExecutionContext().get(Consts.JOB_EXECUTION_MESSAGE_KEY) != null) {
            message = jobExecution.getExecutionContext().getString(Consts.JOB_EXECUTION_MESSAGE_KEY);
        }
        message += "\n" + lastJobExceptionMessage;
        jobExecution.getExecutionContext().put(Consts.JOB_EXECUTION_MESSAGE_KEY, message);
    }

}
```

But I still end with a `JobInterruptedException`.
Is there a way to retrieve the initial cause of the interruption (might be a error in the reader/processor/writer code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your diagnosis is correct. That exception is thrown with that error message only in `SimpleStepHandler`:

```
if (currentStepExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.STOPPING
        || currentStepExecution.getStatus() == BatchStatus.STOPPED) {
    // Ensure that the job gets the message that it is stopping
    execution.setStatus(BatchStatus.STOPPING);
    throw new JobInterruptedException("Job interrupted by step execution");
}
```

and only if the step itself didn't throw `JobInterruptedException`. The most obvious case where this can happen is if the job was stopped. See [this example](https://gist.github.com/cataphract/c1a3031880557fefb9da#file-stopjob-groovy), whose output ends with

```
INFO: Executing step: [step1]
Feb 24, 2016 1:25:02 PM org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository checkForInterruption
INFO: Parent JobExecution is stopped, so passing message on to StepExecution
Feb 24, 2016 1:25:02 PM org.springframework.batch.core.step.ThreadStepInterruptionPolicy isInterrupted
INFO: Step interrupted through StepExecution
Feb 24, 2016 1:25:02 PM org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep execute
INFO: Encountered interruption executing step step1 in job myJob : Job interrupted status detected.
Feb 24, 2016 1:25:02 PM org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository checkForInterruption
INFO: Parent JobExecution is stopped, so passing message on to StepExecution
Feb 24, 2016 1:25:02 PM org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob execute
INFO: Encountered interruption executing job: Job interrupted by step execution
Feb 24, 2016 1:25:02 PM org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1 run
INFO: Job: [SimpleJob: [name=myJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [STOPPED]
Status is: STOPPED
```

[This other example](https://gist.github.com/cataphract/c1a3031880557fefb9da#file-threadpoolexception-groovy) shows that throwing an exception when using a thread pool changes nothing. The final output is

```
INFO: Executing step: [step1]
Feb 24, 2016 1:28:44 PM org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep execute
SEVERE: Encountered an error executing step step1 in job myJob
java.lang.RuntimeException: My exception
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
(...)

Feb 24, 2016 1:28:44 PM org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1 run
INFO: Job: [SimpleJob: [name=myJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [FAILED]
Status is: FAILED, job execution id 0
  #1 step1 FAILED
Step step1
java.lang.RuntimeException: My exception
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
(...)
```

Comment: Ok thanks, so let me reword my question :  what could be the reason for my job/step to get STOPPED in async context that does not happen in a sync one ? And how to find and log that reason

Comment: @CyrilDejonghe I don't know. Try putting a breakpoint in `StepExecution::setStatus` and watch for when the value is `STOPPED` or `STOPPING`.

Comment: I tried to debug for more details but I'm stuck in the darkest depths of Spring-Batch. For example I encountered a NullPointerException in [RepeatTempalte#doHandle()](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2479)  ... I might ask a more generic question about configuring an Async JobLauncher, but the doc seemed pretty clear...

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was so simple than I felt really stupid when I understood it :
@Artefacto was right. The job was stopped. By the end of the process. Because it reached the end of the main() method.

When I switch to an asynchronous mode with my ThreadPoolTaskManager, I forgot to add one very important line to my main method:

```
    // Wait for the end of the JobExecution
    main.endOfJobLatch.await();
```

Hope this answer will help someone else...